# 'non potrà neanche mai'

Tags: grammar

> L'Italia *non potrà neanche mai* iniziare a pensare di uscire dalla recessione strutturale se prima non sopprime regioni e authority.

È corretto scrivere *non potrà neanche mai* lì? O, invece, sarebbe il caso di omettere il *mai*?

Comment: Meglio *nemmeno*, direi; ma il *mai* è certamente di troppo.

Comment: Io non sento necessariamente il *mai* di troppo. La frase si appesantisce un po', questo è vero, però la parola ha il suo significato, che è ragionevole.

Comment: Cosa dice la frase prima? Il _neanche_ forse si riferisce a quello.

Answer (score 5):

Se la frase precedente dice che l'Italia non potrà (mai) fare qualcosa, allora potrebbe essere corretto (ossia il significato sarebbe "né l'una né l'altra cosa"):

> L'Italia non potrà mai fare X. .... e non potrà neanche mai fare Y.

Answer (score 2):

Il mai lo metti se intendi che non potrà mai farlo.
Se invece puoi dire che può farlo ma non in un futuro prossimo allora togli il mai.
Per il neanche, confermo appunto che dovrebbe esserci una negazione in una frase precedente nello stesso paragrafo.